# What is the set of all "pseudo-rational" numbers (see details)?

Tags: real-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, sequences-and-series

Define a “pseudo-rational” number to be a real number $q$ that can be written as

$q=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$

Where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are fixed integer polynomials (independent of n). All rational numbers are pseudo-rational, as is $\pi^2$ using $P(x)=6,Q(x)=x^2$. There must exist numbers that are not pseudo-rational (defined as "pseudo-irrational") because the set of pseudo-rationals is countable. Is $e$ pseudo-rational? Is $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: It is an additive subgroup of the reals in which each number is "slowly"approximable. I don't know if all algebraic numbers are in this group.  I am pretty sure it is not closed under multiplication and that e is not in this subgroup, but I can't prove it yet.  Gerhard "Perhaps It Excludes Liouville Numbers?" Paseman, 2017.01.13.

Comment: Expanding on Gerhard Paseman's comment, the set in question is in fact a subspace of the reals considered a vectr space over the rationals

Comment: Also, you should place certain restrictions on Q and P to avoid division by zero and diverging sums.  It includes values of the zeta function in addition to pi^2/6, and likely some more exotic numbers.  In addition to checking for algebraic and Liouville numbers, I suggest looking at some mathematical constants that may arise from this, particularly work of Steven Finch.  Also, approximation (by rational numbers) theory may help.  Gerhard "Try Diverging Away From Nullity" Paseman, 2017.01.13.

Comment: This question might be completely inaccessible. for example $\zeta(7)$ is pseudorational and hence any rational multiple of it is too. But it could maybe be an open problem to even say whether $e$ is a rational multiple of $\zeta(7)$ -- these things are hard. Maybe someone can come up with a clever proof that (some well-known number) is pseudorational, but most numbers won't be and my guess is that you won't be seeing anyone posting proofs that (some well-known number) is *not*. Here's a question which might be more tractible -- are pseudorational numbers all periods in the sense of Zagier?

Comment: Given P,Q, can we decide whether the pseudorational is positive, or greater than a given algebraic number?  How many terms would we need to calculate?  Those are easier than @KevinBuzzard's question, but still not trivial.

Comment: Since the terms either diverge or grow like $O(n^{-2})$, I think determining positivity and good bounds for the value are routine, especially for small degree denominators.  Gerhard "In Theory If Not Practice" Paseman, 2017.01.14.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, calculating to within epsilon is routine, but that procedure won't tell you about positivity.  How would it work for $P/Q = 6/n^2 - 8/(2n-1)^2$ ?

Comment: I would guess that Liouvilles constant, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html is probably not pseudo-rational...

Comment: It's still an open question whether $e/\pi$ is irrational, so don't expect a proof that $e$ is not pseudorational.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Guesses are easy to make, proofs are something else.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Are you saying that a proof that $e$ is not psuedo-rational would imply that $e/\pi$ is not rational? I'm not sure I follow, since this set doesn't seem to be closed under division

Comment: @ASKASK But they are closed under multiplication by rational numbers: if $e/\pi=k/l$ and $\pi=\sum P(n)/Q(n)$ (see e.g. Matt F.'s answer below), then $e=\sum kP(n)/lQ(n)$.

Answer (score 11):

*One partial answer:*

$\pi$ and $\ln(2)$ are both pseudo-rational:
\begin{align}
\ln(2) &= \sum\frac{1}{2n\,(2n-1)} \\
\pi &= \sum\frac{3}{n\,(2n-1)\,(4n-3)} \\
\end{align}

These follow from statements in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), including Gauss's digamma theorem, and are also asserted by Mathematica.  By similar manipulations, $\pi\sqrt{3}$ and $\ln(3)$ are pseudo-rational also.

$\ $

*Some questions collected from the comments:*

- Are the pseudo-rationals closed under multiplication?
- Are all pseudo-rationals [periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods)?
- Is there a procedure to decide if the pseudo-rational from $P,Q$ is positive?

The last one is difficult because there are non-trivial zeroes like $\sum\left(\dfrac{6}{n^2}-\dfrac{8}{(2n-1)^2}\right)$.

Comment: For $\pi$ there is also the trivial $\sum \frac{8}{(4n-3)(4n-1)}$.

Answer (score 7):

Also possibly of interest:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{2}{b(n-1/b)(n+1/b)} + \frac{b}{n(n+1)}\right) =  \pi \cot(\pi/b)$$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac {t \left( {t}^{2}{n}^{2}+2\,{n}^{2}+2\,n+1 \right) }{ \left( n+
1 \right) n \left( {t}^{2}{n}^{2}+1 \right) }}
 = \pi \coth(\pi/t) $$

EDIT: 
And, if I'm not mistaken,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1-m}{mn} + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{mn-k}\right) = \ln(m) $$
for positive integers $m$.

Comment: I like the expression for the logs.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want lots of examples .... note that, if $a$ is rational and not an integer, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+a-1}\right) = \gamma+\psi(a)
$$
is pseudo-rational.  ($\psi$ is the digamma)
I plugged in $k/12$ for $1 \le k \le 11$ to get these:
$$
-2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) ,\\-1/6\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}-3/2\,\ln  \left( 3
 \right) ,\\-3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -\pi /2,\\-3/2\,\ln  \left( 3
 \right) -2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -1/2\,\pi \,\sqrt {3},\\-1/2\,\sqrt {
3}\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3} \right) -3/2\,\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3}
 \right) -3/4\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 3 \right) -9/4\,\ln  \left( 3
 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( 
\pi /12 \right) -1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( \pi /12 \right) 
\sqrt {3}+3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) +3/2\,\ln  \left( -
3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) \sqrt {3},\\1/6\,\pi \,\sqrt {3}-3/2\,\ln 
 \left( 3 \right) ,\\-3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\pi /2,\\-3/2\,\ln 
 \left( 3 \right) -2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +1/2\,\pi \,\sqrt {3},\\-3/2
\,\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3} \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {
3} \right) -9/4\,\ln  \left( 3 \right) +3/4\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 3
 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( {
\frac {5\,\pi }{12}} \right) \sqrt {3}+1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos
 \left( {\frac {5\,\pi }{12}} \right) -3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3
} \right) \sqrt {3}+3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) ,\\-3/2\,
\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3} \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3}
 \right) -9/4\,\ln  \left( 3 \right) +3/4\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 3
 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( {
\frac {5\,\pi }{12}} \right) \sqrt {3}-1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos
 \left( {\frac {5\,\pi }{12}} \right) -3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3
} \right) \sqrt {3}+3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) ,\\-1/2\,
\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3} \right) -3/2\,\ln  \left( 2-\sqrt {3}
 \right) -3/4\,\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( 3 \right) -9/4\,\ln  \left( 3
 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( 
\pi /12 \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,\cos \left( \pi /12 \right) 
\sqrt {3}+3/2\,\ln  \left( -3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) +3/2\,\ln  \left( -
3+2\,\sqrt {3} \right) \sqrt {3}
$$